# Creating a reusable React.js component with internal events in the Flux architecture

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm following the "containers and components" approach in the following video to build a reusable component in the Flux architecture.

React.js Conf 2015 (22m 50s): https://youtu.be/KYzlpRvWZ6c?t=22m50s

---

For example, I'm building an image slider with the 'next' button.

*ImageSliderContainer*

- Listens to *ImageSliderStore* and maintains states (e.g., currentIndex)
- Renders *ImageSlider* with props

*ImageSlider*

- Stateless component, just rendering based on props
- Has a child component *NextButton*

*NextButton*

- Stateless component, just rendering based on props
- Has onClick event

---

In the Flux architecture, clicking *NextButton* will send an action to a store. Then, a store will update "currentIndex" and emit a change event. It seems to me that *ImageSlider* is not reusable anymore as it's tightly coupled with a single store by which a single container will be notified.

Another option will be to add a state "currentIndex" to the *ImageSlider* component. Clicking *NextButton* will notify *ImageSlider* to update its state. But this will introduce a reverse data flow from *NextButton* to *ImageSlider* (violating the Flux architecture?). Also, it is against the "containers and components" approach in which a component just renders UI using props.

What will be the best way to make a reusable component in the Flux architecture? More specifically, which element (store, container, component, or something else) should handle the onClick event occurring inside *NextButton* component?

---

Edited

Based on answers, here's one solution that satisfies both the Flux architecture and the "containers and components" pattern.

- The container owns the state "currentIndex." The app may have multiple containers such as *ScreenshotSliderContainer* and *DebugSliderContainer*, each of which maintains its own "currentIndex."
- The container passes the onClick handler to the component *ImageSlider* as a prop. The onClick handler sends an action to a store.
- The *ImageSlider* component is stateless, transferring the onClick handler to a child component *NextButton*.
- Consequently, the onClick event in *NextButton* does not affect a top component *ImageSlider*. Only the container renders the *ImageSlider* with new props.

Comment: "Clicking NextButton will notify ImageSlider to update its state. But this will introduce a reverse data flow..." – I don’t understand this sentence. Flux is about uni-directional data flow, but you are talking about a click event that should update a parent component’s internal state. I don’t think this would be a violation to Flux, but you should be clear on what component will *own the state* (closest common ancestor)

Comment: Use props and listen to Flux changes in top components

Comment: @David As described in the linked video, I'm trying to make a reusable component (ImageSlider) stateless, while only a container *owns* the state. It's likely to have multiple containers in the app (e.g., ScreenshotSliderContainer, TestContainer, ...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass down the onClick event handler as a prop, like in the react tutorial:
http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#callbacks-as-props

Comment: I have found that for the most part, I actually only use stores and actions at the very top level of an application. I might pass an action as a callback to a component (Reflux, not FB Flux), but lower level components should be entirely self contained. The top level component integrates their actions with store(s) that are specific to that app.

Comment: I agree with @Dan Ross FB often mentions it's easier to keep all of your state at the highest level, which I've found to be true. If you only have your top most component listening for changes and interacting with the store, it makes the child components super easy to reason about and not tightly coupled. Just pass in props, and they do their thing. Where/when those props come from, they don't care.